# How does operator < or > work when comparing two strings?

Tags: javascript

I used `<` to compare two strings like this:

```
console.log('ca'<'bb'); //false
```

I already know that it compares Unicode number of the character.Because `c` is not less than `b`.

However when I do this:

```
console.log('ba'<'bb');//true
```

Makes me confused, as `b` is not less than `b` itself, seems it just skipped it and compared the next character.

Anyway, I wonder what's the rule here when `<` or `>` is used to compare two strings, and for some complicated situations what if when the two strings have different lengths?

Comment: The ES5 spec [explains it in detail](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5).

Comment: Kind a dictionary match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does exactly as you suggested - it skips characters that are the same in both strings and compares the first different characters by code unit value. This is explained by the [abstract relational comparison algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.8.5) in the spec (emphasis added):

> a. If *py* is a prefix of *px*, return false.
>   b. If *px* is a prefix of py, return true.
>   c. **Let *k* be the smallest nonnegative integer such that the character at position *k* within *px* is different from the character at position *k* within *py*.** (There must be such a *k*, for neither String is a prefix of the other.)
>   d. Let *m* be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position *k* within *px*.
>   e. Let *n* be the integer that is the code unit value for the character at position *k* within *py*.
>   f. If *m < n*, return true. Otherwise, return false.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are compared alphabetically, in this order: first letters, second letters, etc:

```
'ba'<'bb'
```

is true because a < b (a is before b in alphabet)

```
'ca'<'bb'
```

is false because c is after b in alphabet. (c > b)

Answer (score 0):

It's a `lexicographic` comparsion.

It starts with the first letter and goes on until a mismatch.

console.log('ca'<'bb'); //false

```
It starts with c<b ? no. b<c? yes. -> c is 'greater' than b, therefore ca < bb -> false.
```

console.log('ba'<'bb');//true

```
It starts with b<b ? no. b > b? no. They both equal -> continue to next letter.
a < b ? yes. Therefore -> ba < bb -> true.
```

[WIKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order)